# Should one comment differently in functional languages?

Tags: functional-programming, comments

I'm just getting started with functional programming and I'm wondering about the correct way to comment my code.

It seems a little redundant to comment a short function as the names and signature already should tell you everything you need to know. Commenting larger functions also seems a little redundant since they are generally comprised of smaller self-descriptive functions.

What is the correct way to comment a functional program? Should I use the same approach as in iterative programming?

Comment: "since they are generally comprised of smaller self-descriptive functions." — that's, in principle, no different in imperative languages. Still it's often not immediately clear what the large function will do in the end: one _could_ always deduce it from the code itself, but if that takes considerably more time than reading a comment you should provide one.

Comment: I disagree. Since Functional langages dont have side effects you know exactly what it will do in the end, return a value with the given signature

Comment: not all functional languages are pure, some do have side effects.

Comment: But comment what you feel to comment... This is overthink

Comment: Does your project run the risk of having other members who are not familiar with functional languages? They may need some extra help.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The function name should say *what* you're doing.

The implementation will tell you *how* you're doing it.

Use comments to explain *why* you're doing it.

Comment: Great answer, it kills me to see code littered with comments that explain the what and how (which is evident from the code itself) but leaving me to guess the why.

Comment: and this is true regardless of paradigm

Comment: This probably goes without saying, but you should also add comments about what and how in the case that the code is complicated or convoluted and requires such explanation. Of course, code like this should also probably avoided anyways, but that's not always possible.

Comment: While this answer is very simple and simplicity does have a lot of value, it is not entirely true. A function name often does not and can not describe "what" in sufficient detail, so documentation is often necessary(e.g. to describe edge cases). Documentation is frequently inserted in comments.

Comment: Yes, what can't be deduced from the code is **why**. Please don't tell me you are getting data from a database. Please tell me why, especially lesson from previous implementations.

Comment: @luiscubal, the corner cases should be described in contracts, assertions, unit tests, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example (from a real-life functional programming project ideally, but anything will do)? One could argue that in a (pure) functional programming language, there is nothing that a function is "doing", since it's only computing a value. So the question of "why" does not arise at the level of the function. (*Why* that function is called is part of the implementation of the calling function.) By this logic, only functions with side-effects need to have comments. Is this what you're saying?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR "I am not sorting the results since function RetrieveResults already ensures the results are sorted". This is a why(although to be precise it's why something is *not* being done). Similarly, "I am using doSomething() because even though third-party function foo() should give correct results, it has a rare bug in which it doesn't, so we use doSomething() as a temporary fix."

Comment: @luiscubal: Whether a function sorts its output is part of its definition/name: the "what". (In any case I guess one would often write functions not to sort, since sorting can always be easily done with a `sort $` in front of the function.) THe other example is more interesting, but it is a rare case. Are comments rarer in functional programming?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I can't answer to that since I have no access to actual statistics. The metrics website Ohloh seems to have an API. Perhaps you could try to use it to get actual numbers? (if you're OK with getting only a subset of all projects and measuring what people comment instead of what people *should* comment) Not sure if their API covers that sort of thing but it might be worth checking out. If that's not good enough, then I don't know any quick way to find out other than pure blind speculation.

Comment: Arguably, the function name should also explain *why* it's doing it - when it's possible.

Comment: The use of "you" in the answer is ambiguous. I think you meant "what it (the function) is doing", "how it does it". The third point seems OK, I interpret it as "why it's needed".

Answer (score 14):

There definitely **is** a point in this question, as functional programs usually are on a different abstraction level than imperative ones.

Because of this, another style of documentation is needed. In iterative programs a comment may be helpful like in the following code, because the essence of the code is hidden behind boilerplate:

```
// map 'toUpperCase' over 'container' yielding 'result'
Container result = new Container();
for (int i=0; i < container.size(); i++) { 
             result.addToTail(container.atElement(i).toUpperCase());
}
```

But this is clearly nonsense in a functional language:

```
-- map 'toUpperCase' over 'list'
let result = map toUpperCase list
```

Better:

```
-- we need the FooBars in all uppercase for the Frobnitz-Interface
let result = map toUpperCase list
```

Comment: grandpa always tells me to document the why instead of the what. So I would use the last version for imperative code as well.

Comment: Your grandpa is right. I just wanted to demonstrate that certain comments that make sense nevertheless in the imperative realm are absolutely useless in the funtional.

Answer (score 11):

The reason we document a function is that readers don't want or can't read the body of the function. For this reason, one should document large functions, even in functional languages. It does not matter if it's easy to understand what the function does by looking at its implementation.

Comment: A good point. Especially if the reader is using some compiled library and can only see exposed function signatures and their comments. They'll never see the self-descriptive guts of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Functions should be commented, if the function name and parameter names alone do not suffice to specify the [contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

```
// returns a list of Employees    <-- not necessary
def GetEmployeeList: ...

// returns a list of Employees sorted by last name    <-- necessary
def GetEmployeeList: ...
```

In a nutshell, the contract defines what the function expects and what it guarantees. Strictly speaking, if `GetEmployeeList` returns a sorted list but does not say so in either the function name or the comment, a consumer of this function must not rely on this behavior. It's an undocumented implementation detail, and the author of `GetEmployeeList` has the freedom to change this behavior any time.

Answer (score 2):

The comment itself shouldn't contain an *alternative description* to what the code does (that actually is expressed by the code itself), but rather an explaination of the *reasons* why the code is written the way it is.

That said, I don't see any reason why a comment should *per se* be different in a functional language.

Answer (score 1):

I take the same approach to documenting all of my code:

- Use descriptive names,
- Add comments before any reasonably complicated logic if complicated logic can't be avoided,
- Write an overview of the entire system,

If the name and type signature doesn't tell you exactly what the function does, you're usually doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At age 25 you tend to remember things much better. As you get older and you are involved with multiple systems with legacy code (yes, the code you write today will be legacy code in 10-15 years) it can be very helpful if there are comments.